# SPListItem event receiver doesn't execute ItemAdded event

Tags: sharepoint-2010, event-receiver

I've created an item event receiver using SharePoint 2010 and Visual Studio 2010. The event receiver executes `ItemDeleting` but it can't execute `ItemAdding` or `ItemAdded` events.

My problem is I upload images for the item in edit form so I want to open the edit form after adding the new item, So I assume that I can make redirect to the edit page in the Added event of the item.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">   
   <Receivers ListTemplateId="10002">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>SharedItemListEventRecieverItemDeleting</Name>
        <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>     
        <Class>ListDefinitions.ListsEventRecievers.SharedItemListEventReciever.SharedItemListEventReciever</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
    </Receivers>
 </Elements>`
```

Comment: Please post the Elements.xml of your Event Receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For event receiver fire ItemAdding and ItemAdded, you need to change elements.xml as follow:

```
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">   
   <Receivers ListTemplateId="10002">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>SharedItemListEventRecieverItemDeleting</Name>
        <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>     
        <Class>ListDefinitions.ListsEventRecievers.SharedItemListEventReciever.SharedItemListEventReciever</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>

     <Receiver>
        <Name>SharedItemListEventRecieverItemDeleting</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>ListDefinitions.ListsEventRecievers.SharedItemListEventReciever.SharedItemListEventReciever</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>

     <Receiver>
        <Name>SharedItemListEventRecieverItemDeleting</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>     
        <Class>ListDefinitions.ListsEventRecieverSharedItemListEventReciever.SharedItemListEventReciever</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>

    </Receivers>
 </Elements>
```

`